# Career change but utilize current education and experience

Tags: job-change, career-switch

Apologies if I sound absurd, I will try my best to be concise.

1. I have completed my Bachelor of Engg.(Computers) and I have an experience of 9 years as a developer(Java, RDBMS, MongoDB, bit of Linux etc.).
2. I have been keenly interested in field careers like Cartography, Surveying(and relevant geography careers)
3. Web Mapping, Photogrammetry and plethora of GIS careers - from Remote Sensing to GIS Analyst, Specialist are interesting but equally confusing
4. Scientific careers like Hydrology etc. too utilize computer science/engineering skills but I couldn't make any progress understanding this on Internet

To summarize, I wish to switch to the above 'branches'  which :

1. Have a mix of field and office work - not just sitting and coding whole life but understand and map the field activities to applications
2. I wish to utilize my current engg. and software skills but I am ready to go for higher education targeting the above mentioned 'branches'

As far as 'career counseling' is concerned, from LinkedIn to the Internet surveys etc., I have hit a wall.

How shall I proceed ?

Comment: The question is whether I should go for higher education, career counseling or switch jobs? Once I get some guidance about the direction, I can start trying in that direction.

Answer (score 3):

I had similar endeavours; my take is this: If you want something concrete to read I would suggest Robert Greene's "[Mastery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastery_%28book%29)". What you describe is a situation where you have achieved mastery in a specific field and want to transcend to a different one. The optimal way to do it is by using your current skill-set as a leverage. I am sure there would be many companies in the field you are interested in that could use a good developer. While there you will be able to get domain knowledge in an accelerating pace and also interface with the related people. As time goes by you will be able to do the switch. But what you can bring right now to the table in order to start this slow process is your concrete IT skills.

It would be great to have an RDBMS administrator for example that understands the domain and can elevate to see the bigger picture versus someone who is *just* interested in maintaining a database and adding DB experience *only*. Based on that I would suggest approaching companies established on the domain you are interested having your intentions in the cover letter. If there are startups on the field even better: they will moreover need a CS person and you will be able to get the domain knowledge and workloads faster.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, I need to develop a skill set that maps to the IT skills of the companies serving these domains. Or is it something else u meant ?

Comment: You need to use your existing skills for such a company, there will sure be a match, then develop or repurpose them for that domain and gradually start the transition from within the organisation.